Does this sentence have two different meanings?

There will be more difficult tasks.

In this sentence, could it cause the following two kinds of different understanding whether "more" is considered as the comparative form of "many" or part of "more difficult"?


There will be more (difficult tasks). (i.e., more tasks which are difficult) 
There will be (more difficult) tasks. (i.e., tasks which are more difficult)



Your sentence can mean either of your alternatives, and a careful native speaker would seek to avoid ambiguity (if it is not already removed by the context or situation), e.g. there will be more difficult tasks after [this or that task] (meaning 1) -- or -- there will be more difficult tasks than [this or that task] (meaning 2)

It's quite common for users to take a sentence, and ask for its meaning without providing any context. I would be pretty sure that the meaning of this sentence would be less ambiguous if we could view the original text.

It wouldn't normally be ambiguous in real (spoken) language. The stress in 1: There will be more difficult tasks means some or all future tasks will be equal in difficulty to the one(s) we've been talking about (more gets stress because that's the primary item of new information) The stress in 2: There will be more difficult tasks means Some or all future tasks will exceed the difficulty level of the one(s) we've been talking about (difficult gets the stress because that's what will change).

more difficult
less difficult
Those are comparatives.
There will be more difficult tasks [implied: than some other thing].
If both are meant, the sentence would need to read like this:
There will be additional, more difficult tasks.
OR
There will be additional difficult tasks.

Thanks for your answer! But could I see the structure as "more (difficult tasks)", which means "a larger number of difficult tasks"?

I have answered your question and now you are asking it again. That's why I am suggesting additional, which means more. more=additional. |additional, difficult tasks|.
